Is there a simple way in Thunderbird to open an html-Email in a browser?
Is there a button, keyboard shortcut, add-on, ... anything?
If it were, I could use the uBlock Origin and other add-ons in my browser to keep things the way I want, instead of trying to achieve the same things in the thunderbird app.

Step-by-Step Guide to Open HTML Emails in a Web Browser

Open Thunderbird and select the HTML email you want to view.
Instead of clicking on the email to open it in Thunderbird,
right-click on the email and choose "View Source" or "View Message Source" from the context menu (the exact wording may vary depending on your operating system and version of Thunderbird).
A new window or tab will open, displaying the raw HTML code of the email. Copy this code by selecting all of it (Ctrl+A or Cmd+A) and then copying it (Ctrl+C or Cmd+C).
Open your preferred web browser and create a new blank document or tab. Paste the copied HTML code into this document or tab (Ctrl+V or Cmd+V).
The web browser will now render the HTML email, allowing you to view and interact with the formatted content as intended.

reference source

Could you elaborate on step 4 on how to paste into the HTML code, please?

Ctrl+V pastes copied text

That's new to me. Here on Firefox nothing happens using this. I already tried that first all. Then I tried the Firefox inspector to paste the copied source into the html section. Inspector let me paste it, but not use enter on it. (Funnily enough, that happened never before.)
